# Need a Cobol documentation reference

Tags: cobol

Can't find a reference to Cobol documentation that describes my example.

```
     01 staff-record-1. 
            05 staff-id       pic s9(4) comp-5. 
            05 staff-name     pic x(20). 
     01 staff-record-2. 
            05 staff-id       pic s9(4) comp-5. 
            05 staff-name     pic x(20). 
            05 staff-info     pic x(40).

    ....
* i can move value    
     move 'info' to staff-info in staff-record-2
* or (if name is uniq)
     move 'info' to staff-info
```

Where can i find a documentation reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this in Enterprise COBOL for z/OS Language Reference Manual SC27-1408-04 in chapter 8 "Referencing Data Names".

Answer (score 3):

See the GNU Cobol FAQ at http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/gnucobol/

and more importantly, as **this is a world class freebie**...

Gary Cutler's GNU Cobol Programmer's Guide at

http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/GNU%20COBOL%202.0%20Programmers%20Guide.pdf

with short names at

http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/GNUCobol2.pdf

and

http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/GNUCobol2-A4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

[HP COBOL MANUAL](http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/82final/6296/aa-q2g0h-tk.pdf) Section 6.2.1 seems to be appropriate. Or Google for "cobol language reference manual move identifier non-unique"

Comment: Thanks, it is pity that I can mark only one answer as are correct

Answer (score 0):

I have found two references too. 
Thanks Jim for your answer!

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pdthelp/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.debugtool.doc_8.1%2Feqa8ug02388.htm

and

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/c092539568.htm